# Select and Post issue (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a input field, a select and one button for post. This post redirects to "player.php" and from there it searches a name on the database.
The problem is if I search for something that exists or not it always shows the echo "nop"

Main php:

```
<form action="player.php" method="post"/>
    <br>Procurar por jogador ou conta:</br></p>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" /></p>
        <select name="drop">
            <option value="personagem">Personagem</option>
            <option value="pid">PID</option>
            <option value="idconta">ID Conta</option>
            <option value="login">Login</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar" />
```

player.php:

```
if($_POST['submit']){ 
$inputVar = $_POST["drop"];
if ($inputVar = "personagem"){
$busca = $_POST['name']; 
$busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM player WHERE name='$busca'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($busca_query);
$result = $row[0];
    if (($result) > 1 ){
        echo "Encontrado!";
    }else{
        echo "Nop";
    }
}
}
```

/UPDATE:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$inputVar = $_POST["drop"];
if ($inputVar = "personagem"){
$busca = $_POST['name']; 
$busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM player WHERE name='$busca'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($busca_query);
$result = $row[0];
    if (($result) > 1 ){
        echo "Encontrado!";
    }else{
        echo "Nop";
    }
}
print_r($row);
}
```

still not working

message: NopArray ( [0] => [DV]Montz )

no errors

Comment: You're assigning, instead of comparing using `if ($inputVar = "personagem")`. I'm seeing so many of these lately.

Comment: what do you mean? I already have that ^

Comment: *Groan* Here: `if ($inputVar == "personagem")`. Questions like these are considered off-topic, by Stack's standards.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter anyway as I'm not seeing "$inputVar" used later on. @JoaoPaulo, try "print_r($row)" to see what you actually get. Edit: I'd guess that $row[0] is a name and not "1".

Comment: also doesn't work with ==

Comment: Array ( [0] => [DV]Montz )

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You're not even checking for errors, in any way. `if($_POST['submit'])` that should be using `isset()` btw.

Comment: Here: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: tried with isset and it gave me an error saying that I couldn't use isset with this.

Comment: The syntax is `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` - *gave me an error,* doesn't tell me "what" error.

Comment: updated ^ still nothing

Comment: What are you intending to check with your code? Only see if there is a player with the given name in the database? You are currently comparing "[DV]Montz" to "1", which doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: yes, I want to see if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (($result) > 1 ){
```

Since `$result` is a string, and is being compared to integer, it is cast as int, specifically 0, which of course is less than 1.

Change that to

```
if ($result){
```

or

```
if (strlen($result) > 0 ){
```